# Setup dependency injection manager in tests target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a dependency injection manager in my main target. In my tests, I inject manually in most places. However, I am currently adding UI testing, and need to load an image loader in the tests target, one that will load a local placeholder instead of making network calls.

I would like that second concrete implementation not to be part of the main target but only of the tests one. My issue is that I can't figure out a place where to setup my dependency injection manager in the tests target to use that class only defined in the tests..

The main.swift can't create an instance of that test image loader because it's not part of the main target, and it seems like there isn't any piece of code that's run before any test case is executed.

Is there a way to setup a dependency injection manager differently in the test target or am I completly on the wrong path here ?

To give a bit more context, the image loader is used in many places, sometimes nested in subviews of subviews, or also in tableView / collectionView cells. It would be quite a pain to manually inject that loader everywhere in the tests.

Thank you for you time

Comment: The whole point of a dependency manager is that everything is centralized and you can switch services with one line. You should look up articles on dependency injection I don’t think you have it implemented correctly

Comment: Well, that's how we have it setup on the main target and it works as expected. But my issue in the tests is that I can't find a place where to actually register my dependencies..

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a static class. But basically, this is not a good idea to share a state between tests. So better initialize your dependency manager in `setUp()` of your `XCTestCase`. If you wont to reuse it, simply extract this code to separate Factory/Assembly class.